# Code optimization - BigInteger

Tags: java, optimization, biginteger

The code works correctly until I give it a big value - it takes too much time to execute.

Can you give me some advice how to optimize it?

BigInteger type of n parameter is a must, it's a part of the task ;)

```
public static String oddity(BigInteger n) {

    List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    String result = null;
    for (BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
         bi.compareTo(n) <= 0;
         bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        if (n.mod(bi).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            list.add(bi);
    }

    if (list.size() % 2 == 0)
        result = "even";
    else result = "odd";


    return result;
}
```

The purpose of this is to return 'odd' if the number of "n" divisors is odd. Otherwise return 'even'.

Comment: Simplest optimization will be using `int` instead of `List` because only way you use it is checking size. It won't give you much, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: Try to replace `BigInteger` with `long` and `list` with `boolean`.

Comment: The optimization to omit adding that values to a lost will bring some speedup, but remains the fact that these kinds of naive factorizations are always bound to be slow, especially for large numbers. Note that you might first want to optimize by only considering primes. But note that checking if a number is prime can be much slower than a `mod()`, so you'll have to determine the primes first, e.g. with a simple *Sieve*. Then you can apply the primes you found to your factorization code. Note that instead of `if`, you should use `while` and at the same time divide `bi` by any divisor you found.

Comment: Also searching up to `n` is a waste of time. Search up to `sqrt(n)` only. I don't know if Java's `BigInteger` has a `sqrt()` function, but it is easy to write if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking rather than just programming would help a lot. You don't need to find all divisors. You don't even need to count them. All you need is to find out if the count is odd.

**But divisors always come in pairs: For every divisor `i` also `n/i` is a divisor.**

So the count is always even, except when there's a divisor `i` equal to `n/i`. Use Guava [sqrt](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#sqrt(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) ...

Answer (score 0):

As you don't use the `list` except to get its final size, you could use an integer as a counter, i.e: do `n++` instead of `list.add(bi)`.
This is going to save huge amount of memory. Hence save time used to manage its allocation.

Comment: Yees, know i see it ! ;) it was unnecessary but it still take to long to execute :/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Lambda
long counter = IntStream
            .range(1, (int) Math.sqrt(n.longValue())+1)
            .filter(i -> n.longValue() % i == 0 && n.longValue() / i == i)
            .count();
    return (counter % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd";
```